# Read an xml file in Python

Tags: python, xml

I am reading a file with a jml extension. The code is very simple and it reads

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('VOAPoints_2010_M25.jml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

but I get a parsing error:

```
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 75, column 16
```

the file I am trying to read is a dataset that has been used before so I am confident that there are no problems with it.

The file is 
[image]
[image]
Can anyone help ?

Comment: Post the XML file contents

Comment: Chances are, that there really IS a problem, but since nobody is enforced to validate, it may have gone unnoticed.

Comment: Could it be the fact that the file is .jml and I treat it as a .xml ? This is the first time I work with this type of files.

Comment: Just in case, please remove the pound symbol in line 75 and replace with a simpler L . It could be the encoding

Comment: Yes it is that indeeed !! Thank you @malarres. My poor understanding of this type of data made my panic.

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for using an answer as a question, but formatting this inside a comment is painful. 
Does the code below solve your problem?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
myParser = ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
tree = ET.parse('VOAPoints_2010_M25.jml',parser=myParser)
root = tree.getroot()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the pound sign was the issue, you can escape it with the [character entity](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) `&#163;`. Python can even automate the replace in XML file by iteratively reading each line and replacing it conditionally on the pound symbol:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

oldfile = "VOAPoints_2010_M25.jml"
newfile = "VOAPoints_2010_M25_new.jml"

with open(oldfile, 'r') as otxt:
    for rline in otxt:
        if "£" in rline:
            rline = rline.replace("£", "&#163;")

        with open(newfile, 'a') as ntxt:
            ntxt.write(rline)

tree = ET.parse(newfile)
root = tree.getroot()
```